# Clarification on AWS Redshift pricing per node

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-redshift

I am currently using a AWS Redshift ra3.xlplus cluster with 2 nodes. The pricing assistant on the resizing screen in the AWS Console say that this configuration costs $1,560/month which gives me 64TB of storage at $0.024/GB/month and "Pay only for the amount of data you store in managed storage".

My use case is sporadically compute intensive, so I would like to scale up to 6 or 12 nodes to speed things up. However, this dramatically increases the estimated monthly price in the resizing summary.

However, I don't need more storage (6 or 12 nodes maxes out at 192TB and 384TB, respectively). Back of the envelope calculations suggest that estimated monthly price is solely dependent on the number of GB used per month. Is this true? If so, does this mean that I will be charged the same amount regardless of how many nodes I have so long as my managed storage footprint does not change?

Comment: Have you given a look at [concurrency scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/concurrency-scaling.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the restrictions on concurrency scaling make it impossible for my use case. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Back of the envelope calculations suggest that estimated monthly price is solely dependent on the number of GB used per month. Is this true? If so, does this mean that I will be charged the same amount regardless of how many nodes I have so long as my managed storage footprint does not change?

Yes, this is correct.

BTW, don't use Concurrency Scaling.  I am of the view it is a (and expensive) band aid for an improperly operated Redshift cluster (but very nearly almost all Redshift clusters are improperly operated).

Comment: Thanks Max. Just to clarify that I understand correctly, you're saying I should have no change in price if I scale up from 2 to 12 nodes so long as the amount of data in storage does not change, correct?

Comment: No.  You pay for the nodes you have, and you pay for the storage you have.  Increasing the number of nodes increases the price.  Increasing the amount of storage increases the price.  I understood the question to be : if I change the number of nodes, does the price for the amount of store I use change?  the answer to that is no.  However, if you keep the storage constant, and increase the number of nodes, you do indeed pay more.

Comment: Ah, I suppose it was too good to be true. Do you happen to know what the pricing is just for the additional nodes if storage remains unchanged? Or where I can find that info? All of AWS's documentation appears to make price estimates based solely in terms of maxing out storage at the monthly level (e.g. $0.024/GB/month x ___TB = $____/month, but no mention of cost of the nodes themselves). I could really use the extra CPUs, but would prefer not to double/triple/more the monthly cost just to get them.

Comment: With `ra3`, you pay 24.5 USD per month per terabyte of store.  This is independent of the number of nodes.

Comment: right, but i have been unable to find any information on pricing for the nodes themselves (when attempting to resize, each additional node comes with additional storage). Specifically what I need to know is the `ra3` monthly price per node holding storage utilized constant at 1TB, so 1 node with 1TB total vs. 12 nodes with 1TB total.

Comment: Yes.  I find it hard to find pricing information on the AWS site, and I know it exists and I've seen it a hundred times.  You want this; https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/pricing/ and in the index click on "On-demand pricing".